# Publish database project using MsBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, database-project

I have a database project in my solution. It comes with the `Local.Datatabase.publish.xml`. After building the project, if I double click on the xml file, I'm able to publish the changes to my local database.

I like to automate this process. Using `MsBuild`, I like to be able to do the same thing.

> I've set `$msbuild` to
>   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`

Unfortunately, `$msbuild /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Local.Database.publish.xml"` isn't working.

How can I publish a database project using MsBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database projects create `bacpac` files after build. I can use the `sqlpackage`, and funnel the connection string in as the parameter.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\SQLPackage.exe" /a:Publish /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=Database; Integrated Security=SSPI;" /SourceFile:"D:\project\bin\Debug\projectname.dacpac"
```

[image]

Comment: The file type is .dacpac.

Comment: There's both dacpac and bacpac.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this by adding some additional build targets to your .sqlproj file.

Add this to the bottom of your .sqlproj file, above the `</Project>` tag:

```xml
  <!--
    Custom targets and properties added so that we can specify the database to publish to using command line parameters with VS 2012+ .sqlproj projects, like we did with VS 2010 .dbproj projects.
    This allows us to specify the MSBuild command-line parameters TargetDatabaseName, and TargetConnectionString when Publishing, and PublishToDatabase when Building.
    I also stumbled across the undocumented parameter, PublishScriptFileName, which can be used to specify the generated sql script file name, just like DeployScriptFileName used to in VS 2010 .dbproj projects.
    Taken from: https://blog.danskingdom.com/using-msbuild-to-publish-a-vs-2012-ssdt-sqlproj-database-project-the-same-way-as-a-vs-2010-dbproj-database-project/
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != '' Or '$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
    <PublishToDatabase Condition="'$(PublishToDatabase)' == ''">False</PublishToDatabase>
    <TargetConnectionStringXml Condition="'$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
      &lt;TargetConnectionString xdt:Transform="Replace"&gt;$(TargetConnectionString)&lt;/TargetConnectionString&gt;
    </TargetConnectionStringXml>
    <TargetDatabaseXml Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != ''">
      &lt;TargetDatabaseName xdt:Transform="Replace"&gt;$(TargetDatabaseName)&lt;/TargetDatabaseName&gt;
    </TargetDatabaseXml>
    <TransformPublishXml>
      &lt;Project xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"&gt;
      &lt;PropertyGroup&gt;$(TargetConnectionStringXml)$(TargetDatabaseXml)&lt;/PropertyGroup&gt;
      &lt;/Project&gt;
    </TransformPublishXml>
    <!-- In order to do a transform, we HAVE to change the SqlPublishProfilePath -->
    <SqlPublishProfilePath Condition="'$([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($(SqlPublishProfilePath)))' == 'False'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(SqlPublishProfilePath)</SqlPublishProfilePath>
    <TransformOutputFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Transformed_$(TargetDatabaseName).publish.xml</TransformOutputFile>
    <TransformScope>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</TransformScope>
    <TransformStackTraceEnabled Condition="'$(TransformStackTraceEnabled)'==''">False</TransformStackTraceEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(PublishToDatabase)'=='True'">
    <CallTarget Targets="Publish" />
  </Target>
  <UsingTask TaskName="ParameterizeTransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <!-- If TargetDatabaseName or TargetConnectionString, is passed in then we use the tokenize transform to create a parameterized sql publish file -->
  <Target Name="BeforePublish" Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != '' Or '$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
    <Message Text="TargetDatabaseName = '$(TargetDatabaseName)', TargetConnectionString = '$(TargetConnectionString)', PublishScriptFileName = '$(PublishScriptFileName)', Transformed Sql Publish Profile Path = '$(TransformOutputFile)'" Importance="high" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists($(SqlPublishProfilePath))" Text="The SqlPublishProfilePath '$(SqlPublishProfilePath)' does not exist, please specify a valid file using msbuild /p:SqlPublishProfilePath='Path'" />
    <ParameterizeTransformXml Source="$(SqlPublishProfilePath)" IsSourceAFile="True" Transform="$(TransformPublishXml)" IsTransformAFile="False" Destination="$(TransformOutputFile)" IsDestinationAFile="True" Scope="$(TransformScope)" StackTrace="$(TransformStackTraceEnabled)" SourceRootPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SqlPublishProfilePath>$(TransformOutputFile)</SqlPublishProfilePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

You can then build and publish your database from the command line like this:

```bash
MSBuild /t:Build /p:TargetDatabaseName="[DbName]";TargetConnectionString="Data Source=[Db.Server];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" /p:PublishToDatabase="True" /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Template.publish.xml" "[PathToBranch]\Database\Database.sqlproj"
```

Or build the project once and deploy it to multiple databases like this:

```bash
MSBuild /t:Build "[PathToBranch]\Database\Database.sqlproj"
MSBuild /t:Publish /p:TargetDatabaseName="[DbName1]";TargetConnectionString="Data Source=[Db.Server];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" /p:PublishScriptFileName="[DbName1].sql" /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Template.publish.xml" "[PathToBranch]\Database\Database.sqlproj"
MSBuild /t:Publish /p:TargetDatabaseName="[DbName2]";TargetConnectionString="Data Source=[Db.Server];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" /p:PublishScriptFileName="[DbName2].sql" /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Template.publish.xml" "[PathToBranch]\Database\Database.sqlproj"
MSBuild /t:Publish /p:TargetDatabaseName="[DbName3]";TargetConnectionString="Data Source=[Db.Server];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" /p:PublishScriptFileName="[DbName3].sql" /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Template.publish.xml" "[PathToBranch]\Database\Database.sqlproj"
```

See [this blog post](https://blog.danskingdom.com/using-msbuild-to-publish-a-vs-2012-ssdt-sqlproj-database-project-the-same-way-as-a-vs-2010-dbproj-database-project/) for the full details.